# Plotting CSV data with python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I have a naive question about plotting csv data with python.

I have a csv file looks like:

```
SubjID SubjGrp GoRT SSRT  StopPoss
1   control 568.56  320.22  0.58
2   control 680.08  314.84  0.54
```

I want to plotting those data like:
[image]

I tried following syntax:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1=csv2rec('stop-allrun-2.csv',delimiter='\t', names=['SubjID', 'GoRT','SSRT','StopPoss'])

x=d1['SubjID']

y=['GoRT']

plot(x,y)
```

then popup the error message:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Is there anything I can do to improve this script?

Comment: You probably want to replace y=['GoRT'] with y=d1['GoRT'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the space as a delimiter (`' '`), then get all data except the column name and convert it from string to integer or float.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from matplotlib.mlab import *

d1=csv2rec('stop-allrun-2.csv',delimiter=' ', names=['SubjID', 'SubjGrp', 'GoRT','SSRT','StopPoss'])

x = tuple(d1['SubjID'][1:])

subjid = tuple(map(int, d1['SubjID'][1:]))
gorts = tuple(map(float, d1['GoRT'][1:]))
ssrts = tuple(map(float, d1['SSRT'][1:]))

width = 0.35
ind = np.arange(len(x))

print(x, gorts, ind)

fig, ax = subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind - width, subjid, width, color = 'y')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind, gorts, width, color = 'r')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind + width, ssrts, width, color = 'b')

ax.set_ylabel('msec')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0]), ('SubjID', 'GoRT', 'SSRT'))

show()
```

This is the result:

[image]

It should work with both pyhon2 and python3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

d1=mlab.csv2rec('stop-allrun-2.csv',skiprows=1,delimiter='\t', names=['SubjID','SubjGrp', 'GoRT','SSRT','StopPoss'])#.astype('float')

x=d1['SubjID']

y=d1['GoRT']

plt.plot(x,y)
```